# Should a child honor a parent’s wish even if the parent does not “benefit” from the child’s compliance?

Tags: kibbud-av-veim-honoring

Does a child have to obey a parent's wish if it is something that does not pertain to them(the parent)?

What is the halacha lmasysa?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) DYH and thanks for this first question. You might want to give more details to ensure you give quality answers, e.g., an example or two, and to make sure the title is well aligned with the question. Also it is not clear who is the "them" at the end: parents or children. Welcome again, great to have you learn with us!

Comment: How could they not benefit? Simply doing what they said will give them the benefit of their directive being followed

Comment: @dude what benefit exactly is that?

Comment: You don't understand that parents have gratification from their children listening to them and doing what they are told?

Comment: You think that's benefit?

Comment: @dude what if they tell you to do something and they don't know if you're doing it? Ex they ask you to do something and then you cut off all contact?